# compare two files line by line in python

Tags: python

I want to compare two different files in python. They contain lines with probabilities, and each line has an in id in the end of the file. I need to calculate ratio of each id.  The problem is that each line might contain different number of probabilities and eventually, each text a different number of lines.  I succeeded in doing a script that compares just two files with one line, but I do not know how to do it for each line in the text. Here is my script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math
import operator
f = open('output.txt','w')
file1= open("test.ppx1","r")
file2= open("test.prob1","r")
words = list(file1.read().split())
words2 = list(file2.read().split())
id1=words[-1]
id2=words2[-1]
words.remove(id1)
words2.remove(id2)
words[:]=[x[:12] for x in words]
words2[:]=[x[:12] for x in words2]
words=map(float,words)
words2=map(float,words2)
words=[math.log(y,10) for y in words]
words2=[math.log(y,10) for y in words2]
words=sum(words)
words2=sum(words2)
ratio= words-words2
print >>f, id1,words, words2,ratio
```

Comment: Could you show examples of the two files as well?

Comment: 2.506201e-08 2.346253e-02 1.282699e-02 3.336181e-05 1.821797e-07 1.424501e-07  utt-0000000001
2.506201e-08 2.346253e-02 1.282699e-02 3.336181e-05 1.821797e-07 1.424501e-07  utt-0000000002
2.506201e-08 2.346253e-02 1.282699e-02 3.336181e-05 1.821797e-07 1.424501e-07  utt-0000000003 for the first file

Comment: 2.506201e-08 2.346253e-02 1.282699e-02 3.336181e-05 1.821797e-07 1.424501e-07 2.506201e-08 1.821797e-07 1.424501e-07 utt-0000000001
2.506201e-08 2.346253e-02 1.282699e-02 3.336181e-05 1.821797e-07 1.424501e-07  utt-0000000002
2.506201e-08 2.346253e-02 1.282699e-02 3.336181e-05 1.821797e-07 1.424501e-07  1.424501e-07 1.424501e-07 utt-0000000003

Comment: First you should read the files line by line (`for line in file1: ...`) instead of loading everything in a large list of words....

Comment: @oezlem Just to clarify: every number you gave is in a new line?

Comment: the second one was a little complicated, it is like in the first one, after utt-numbers is a new line

Answer (score 1):

You might want to zip the read contents of both files and iterate over them. Note that when you use zip, for file of varying line lengths, all files get to have the length of the shortest smallest file length. See [Documentation of zip builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
import math


file_list = []

with open("test.ppx1", "r") as file1:
    file_list.append(file1.readlines())

with open("test.prob1", "r") as file2:
    file_list.append(file2.readlines())

with open('output.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for file1_str, file2_str in zip(*file_list):
        file1_list = file1_str.split()
        file2_list = file2_str.split()
        id1, id2 = file1_list.pop(),  file2_list.pop()
        p1 = map(float, file1_list)
        p2 = map(float, file2_list)
        p1 = map(lambda y: math.log(y, 10), p1)
        p2 = map(lambda y: math.log(y, 10), p2)
        s1, s2 = sum(p1), sum(p2)
        ratio = s1 - s2
        file_out.write("{} {} {} {}".format(id1, s1, s2, ratio))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log2.py", line 11, in <module>
    p1 = map(float, file1_list.split())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: .
 I have this error

Comment: I have revised the answer. I never thought about the ids not being convertable to floats.